# Page should refresh when click cancel on confirm box

Tags: javascript, visualforce, confirm

```
return confirm('Changing the protocol will reset the project Team members');
                }
```

I am calling two methods onclick, first one is stopping to click button multiple times, second one displaying confirm box. once user clicks cancel, user unable to save it again. i am looking for solution to differentiate these two meathods on click.

```
<apex:commandButton onclick=" this.onclick=function(){return false;}; return showProtocolEditWarning();" action="{!save}" value="Save" id="commandButtonSave"/>  

 function showProtocolEditWarning(){
            if(projectId && praProtocol){
                var newProject = document.querySelector('input[id$="inputFieldPraProject_lkid"]').value;
                var protocolIdElement = document.querySelector('select[id$="protocolIdList"]');
                var newProtocol = protocolIdElement.options[protocolIdElement.selectedIndex].value;
                if(praProject.substring(0,15) != newProject.substring(0,15) || praProtocol != newProtocol){
                    return confirm('Changing the protocol will reset the project Team members');
                    //window.location.reload() ;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Use `location.reload()` to refresh the page.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `confirm(...)`, you should check what the user clicked, and reload the page using `location.reload()` if the user clicked cancel:

```js
function confirmMessage() {
  if(confirm('Your confirmation msg')) { //i.e. if the user pressed ok
    //handle this
  }
  else {  //i.e. user pressed cancel
    location.reload();
  }
}
```